# PHP Split string in key value pairs

Tags: php, arrays, split, explode

I know this has been asked before but this is a bit different.

I have a string like:

> [de]Text1[fr]Text2[en]Text3

that I need to split in key-value pairs like

> array('de'=>'Text','fr'=>'Text','en'=>'Text')

I do it like this at the moment, but this is not very elegant (and produces an empty object at the first place in the array:

```
$title = '[de]Text1[fr]Text2[en]Text3';

$titleParts = explode('[',$title);

$langParts;
foreach($titleParts as $titlePart){
    $langPart = explode(']',$titlePart);
    $langParts[$langPart[0]] = $langPart[1];
}

print_r($langParts);
```

Output:

> Array ( [] => [de] => Text1 [fr] => Text2 [en] => Text3 )

Comment: What are you actually trying to do ?

Comment: As written, I need to split a string (given above) into key-value pairs (given above) as per my code (given above) but more elegant. But thanks for the downvote anyway...

Comment: Why not make an Json array?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```php
$title = '[de]Text1[fr]Text2[en]Text3';
preg_match_all('~\[([^[]+)\]([^[]+)~', $title, $match);
$output = array_combine($match[1], $match[2]);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/313112)</kbd>

<sub>Your example will also work with minimal change: <kbd>[demo](https://eval.in/313117)</kbd></sub>

Comment: Ah, we did same preg_match_all(). I'll delete mine

Comment: @Rasclatt: you didn't need to do that, your pattern was different, and the loop also, so the answer is different...

Comment: Yeah, approach is the same though, I'll undelete it, but I don't know that my preg_match expression is as good as yours.

Comment: And your `array_combine()` is genius. Yours is better all around! Nice.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `preg_match_all()`:

```
<?php
    $title = '[de]Text1[fr]Text2[en]Text3';
    preg_match_all('/([\[a-z\]]{1,})([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})/',$title,$match);

    if(isset($match[2])) {
            foreach($match[1] as $key => $value) {
                    $array[str_replace(array("[","]"),"",$value)] = $match[2][$key];
                }
        }
    print_r($array);
?>
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [de] => Text1
    [fr] => Text2
    [en] => Text3
)
```